# Why cant the Count() operator be used in a where clause? how do i get around this?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to write a query to return the town, and the number of runners from each town where the number of runners is greater than 5.

My Query right now look like this:

> select hometown, count(hometown) from marathon2016 where count(hometown) > 5 group by hometown order by count(hometown) desc;

but sqlite3 responds with this:

> Error: misuse of aggregate: count()

What am i doing wrong, Why cant I use the count() here, and what should I use instead.

Answer (score 1):

When you're trying to use an aggregate function (such as `count`) in a WHERE cause, you're usually looking for [HAVING](https://sqlite.org/lang_select.html#resultset) instead of WHERE:

```
select hometown, count(hometown)
from marathon2016
group by hometown
having count(*) > 5
order by count(*) desc
```

You can't use an aggregate in a WHERE cause because aggregates are computed across multiple rows (as specified by GROUP BY) but WHERE is used to filter individual rows to determine what row set GROUP BY will be applied to (i.e. WHERE happens before grouping and aggregates apply after grouping).

Comment: @BryceEdwards if this answer helped you, you need to accept it by clicking on the check mark underneath the voting buttons. That way other visitors can easily see how you solved your problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
select
    hometown, 
    count(hometown) as hometown_count
from
    marathon2016 
group by 
    hometown
having
    hometown_count > 5
order by 
    hometown_count desc;
```

Comment: So is there no way to only get the results where only towns with more than 5 people are listed?

Comment: @BryceEdwards I misunderstood your question. Updated my answer.